# touch scrolling on mobile not working modernizr.js used

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr, touchmove

For this code in mobile if i touch and move body it does not move but if touch header or footer and move it scrolls could any one please help...

But in my(iphone) or some mobiles it works it does not work in some other mobiles
You can check by using browser emulator it does not work there
I sense the problem is in modernizr.js could any one please help

```
<div class="vs-wrapper">
        <section id="section-1">
          <div class="vs-content">
           <div id="portfolio-content" class="center-text">
            <div class="portfolio-page">
                <div class="portfolio-group">
                    <a class="portfolio-item" href="images/paper.jpg">
                        <img src="images/paper.jpg" alt="image 1">
                        <div class="detail">
                            some text or ptag goes here

                        </div>
                    </a>                
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you edit this and add in your JS code? I assume you're pretty new to StackOverflow. Whenever you post a question, it's very important you provide as good an example as possible. Here, it will be pretty close to impossible to help you unless you add the JS code that does not work. Also, try to add just enough to understand and test instead of the whole thing.

Comment: sorry i thought that file modernizr.js is common file that can be found in internet

Comment: here is the link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6rLG996YpiNdTJYZGYtdzJ3Z28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Posting the link to download an unknown JS file from the Internet is a Very Bad Idea. Please edit your question and add the code there. Also, how are you using this library? How do you load, init and call it?